# @ApiModelProperty(position = "") not working in swagger 2.9.2 version

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, position

```
@Data
public class PerfumeSaveRequestDto {
    @ApiModelProperty(position = 0)
    private String brandName;
    @ApiModelProperty(position = 1)
    private String koreanName;
    @ApiModelProperty(position = 2)
    private String englishName;
    @ApiModelProperty(position = 3,example = "15000")
    private int price;
    @ApiModelProperty(position = 4)
    private List<Integer> volume;
    @ApiModelProperty(position = 5,example = "1")
    private int priceVolume;
    @ApiModelProperty(position = 6)
    private String topNote;
    @ApiModelProperty(position = 7)
    private String heartNote;
    @ApiModelProperty(position = 8)
    private String baseNote;
}
```

In the code above, positions are not sorted, but sorted alphabetically.
How should I correct it?

I expected it to be aligned according to the position I wrote, but it wasn't.

Comment: Does it work when not using Lombok? I'd try that first.